# What's a good strategy to move data from a SQL database to Google NDB?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Hello there fellow netizens,

I have a SQL database (about 600MB big) that I want to import into my GAE app. I know that one possibility would be to simpy use Google Cloud SQL, but I'd rather have the data available in NDB to get the benefits thereof. So I'm wondering, how should I think about converting the SQL schema into a NDB schemaless structure? Should I simply set up Kinds to mirror each table? How ought I deal with foreign keys that relate different tables?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!
- Lee

Answer (score 1):

1. How should I think about converting the SQL schema into a NDB schemaless structure?

If you are planning to transfer your SQL data to the Datastore, you need to think about how these two systems are very different.

2. Should I simply set up Kinds to mirror each table?

In thinking about making this transfer, simple analogies like this will only get you so far. Thinking SQL on a schemaless DB can get you in serious trouble due to the difference in implementation, even if at first it helps to think of a Kind as a table, Entity properties as columns, etc... In short, no, you should not simply set up Kinds to mirror each table. You *could*, but it depends what kind of operations you want to support on these entities, how often these ops will occur, what kind of queries your system relies on, etc...

3. How ought I deal with foreign keys that relate different tables?

Honestly, if you're looking to use MySQL specific features like foreign keys, or your data model will require a lot of rethinking. A "foreign key" could be as little as maintaining a key reference to the other Kind in an Entity of a certain Kind.

I would suggest that you stick with Cloud SQL if your data storage solution is already built in SQL, unless you are willing to A) rethink your whole data model B) implement the new data model C) transfer the data you currently have D) re-code all code that interacts with data storage (unless using ORM, in which case your life might be easier for this aspect).

Depending how complex your SQL db is, and how much time you feel it will take to migrate to Datastore, and how much time/brainpower you are willing to commit to learning a new system and new ways of thinking, you should either stick with SQL or do the above steps to rebuild your data storage solution.